# Undefined variable in view laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this code here which is listing all items from one user, user and item are two differents model and they have relationship with their primary keys.

```
@foreach($user->items as $item)
    <p class="heading">
         <a href="">{{ $item->item_id }}</a>
     </p>
@endforeach
```

My question is how to send that `item_id` with post request to controller, because when I write like this for example `<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('preview', $item->item_id) }}" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">` it gives me that $item variable is not defined.

My controller:

```
public function preview($item_id){

        return view('itempreview')->with('item_id', $item_id);
    }
```

Any ideas how to send that `item_id`?

Comment: The `$item` variable isn't defined until your `foreach` loop so you should be putting the form inside that loop.

Comment: so is there any way to send that item_id ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `$item_id` as part of the POST:

```
@foreach($items as $item) 
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('preview') }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ $item->item_id }}">
    </form>
@endforeach
```

Then in the method that receives the POST:

```
public function index() {

     $item_id = request()->input('item_id');

     return view('preview');
}
```

Comment: I have function in controller, but it gives me error in this line `<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('preview', $item->item_id) }}" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">` that this variable is not defined

Comment: you didn't understand my question, i don't need to show all items, I'm listing that items from one user, but I need that user_id to send to another controller

Comment: yes it's a model, the controller doesnt make any problems here, the error is something with action parameter...

Comment: It will work like that, but is there way without making hidden input, also i want to send that parameter with request because i want my route to be like /preview/{item_id}

Comment: It depends on how your route is set up. Do you have the route parameter set up? e.g. `Route::post('preview/{item_id}')`

Comment: Yes it is like that

Comment: try `<form action="{{ route('preview') }}/{{ $item->item_id }}">`

Answer (score 0):

You should use array as 2nd param to `route()` method!

You are doing it wrong, you should send it like this:

```
route('preview', ['item_id' => $item->item_id]);
```

Make sure, your route should be defined as this:

```
Route::post('preview/{item_id}', 'ControllerName@preview')->name('preview');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What are you doing inside controller, can you show me the code?

Comment: I am updating my answer soon!

Comment: I update the question with the code from the controller

Comment: Is it a POST request `route('preview');` ?

Comment: Yes it's post request

Comment: My route is defined like your code, but the problem is not the route and the controller, the problem now is with sending post parameter, it gives me that item variable is not defined.